# How to do groupby in Datatable column where Column Datatype is Dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to do GroupBy on Datatable column where Datatype of column is dynamic.
i.e.

```
  public List<string> GetGroupBy(DataTable dt, String ColumnDatatype, String ColumnName)
    {
        return (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                group r by new
                {
                    GrpList = r.Field<ColumnDatatype>(ColumnName)
                } into g
                select new { g.Key.GrpList }).ToList();
    }
```

this can not taking ColumnDatatype giving me error. I am using framework 3.5.

How can do above thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the indexer instead of `Field<T>` like this:

```
return (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
        group r by r[ColumnName] into g
        select new { g.Key.GrpList }).ToList();
```